# Incorrect implementation of stack datatype using linked list in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I have just started learning Data Structure and I've been trying to implement them in C. In this piece of C code, I am trying to implement a stack using linked lists. I used gdb to figure out the BUG comments. I do not know how to solve this problem (or even why this problem is occurring).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Linked List (As a stack, following LIFO principle)
// Dynamic size
typedef struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Prototypes
void push(node *list, int number);
int pop(node *list);
void free_list(node *list);

int main(void)
{
    // Making empty linked list
    node *list = NULL;

    // Adding elements to list
    push(list, 1);
    // BUG: Here, the value of list is not changed

    printf("%i\n", list->number);

    // Freeing list
    free_list(list);

    return 0;
}

void push(node *list, int number)
{
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        puts("Could not allocate memeory for element");
        return;
    }

    temp->number = number;
    temp->next = list;

    list = temp; 
    // BUG: Value getting assigned here
}

int pop(node *list)
{
    if (list == NULL)
        return 0;

    node *temp = list;

    int number = list->number;
    list = list->next;

    free(temp);

    return number;
}

void free_list(node *list)
{
    while (list != NULL)
    {
        node *temp = list->next;
        free(list);
        list = temp;
    }
}
```

Some help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Yeah...you do not understand the basics of arguments and parameters.  'func(sometype x)' cannot mutate 'x' because the 'x' argument is COPIED into the parameter in the function.

Comment: There is a difference between passing a variable to a function [by value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_value.htm) and [by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm). You are passing the variable by value, when you should be passing it by reference. When you pass a variable by value, you are passing a copy of the variable to the function, so if the function modifies its variable, only the copy gets modified, and the original variable is not modified. This is not the case if you pass by reference.

Comment: Yeah.. I feel stupid. It was obvious. I should just set the arg as the pointer to a pointer. Thanks